# Best practice to navigate between screens in a GUI program

Tags: user-interface, navigation, window

I am studying GUI programming an am doing fine for very simple GUI scripts, but since the opportunities to prototype a bit larger, more complete "real world" programs, I'm having some doubts.

Specifically, I don't know how should I handle navigation between screens. For example:

- I create a window
- I create the window's content (a panel widget with lots of widgets)
- One of the widgets, when clicked, "takes to another screen"

This "other screen" is supposedly something that replaces the current window content. But what should the program actually do?
 - Destroy the panel widget?
 - Hide/remove the panel widget, but let it "live" in memory, offscreen?

Destroying the whole window and creatin another one is most probably NOT the way to do it.

Some form of navigation (backtrack) is something I plan to achieve.

The core of the question is: how is it USUALLY done, on most programs - what is the "usual", or "current" or "obvious" way to do it?

Thanks for reading, and sorry if the question is confuse and/or vague.

(note: I use PyGTK, but I'd like to think que question is toolkit-agnostic)

Answer (score 0):

The first window is the parent window and the window on a click or navigation can be your child window.. you can have a grand child window, grand grand child window, etc.

You need not delete the parent window.  The child windows can be drawn on top of it.

Comment: When you say "draw on top", this means hiding the content of the main window?